# Problem listing blobs in azure hierarchily using Go

Tags: azure, go, azure-blob-storage

In python this works:

```py
container_client.walk_blobs(name_starts_with=path + "/", delimiter="/")
```

It will allow me to iterate over top level "directories" in the blob storage.

I'm attempting to do the same in Go like this:

```golang
func getModelsHierarchy(client *azblob.Client, containerName string, directory string) {
    maxResults := int32(200)
    delimiter := "/"

    containerClient := client.ServiceClient().NewContainerClient(containerName)
    pager := containerClient.NewListBlobsHierarchyPager(delimiter, &container.ListBlobsHierarchyOptions{
        Include:    container.ListBlobsInclude{},
        MaxResults: &maxResults,
        Prefix:     &directory,
    })

    for pager.More() {
        resp, err := pager.NextPage(context.TODO())
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        for _, blob := range resp.ListBlobsHierarchySegmentResponse.Segment.BlobItems {
            fmt.Println("Adding model " + *blob.Name)
        }
    }
}
```

According to docs at https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/storage/azblob@v1.0.0/container#Client.NewListBlobsHierarchyPager I think this should work. I've tested with a blob storage and a data lake gen 2 with hierarchy turned on. I have checked that there are files and directories using the web storage explorer.

Results:

With "/" as delimiter I get no results back. With "_" as delimiter I get *all* files back.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, the problem is that you want to iterate over the folders, and not the blobs? Can you add a bit more info about what the problem is and what you want to achieve? (BTW I ran your code and got the same results so far)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood, you want to iterate *only* over the directories (not the blobs). As mentioned in [this discussion](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/issues/18921), this is currently not natively supported by the Go SDK.

The REST API supports it via the [`showonly={deleted,files,directories}`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs?tabs=azure-ad#uri-parameters) URI parameter, however it looks like the SDK did not implement this translation. I looked over the code and couldn't find it, nor a way to hack it into the REST GET string var.

Perhaps a workaround is to do a REST API implementation directly using one of these [authentication methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-requests-to-azure-storage).

Comment: Yes, that's my conclusion as well. Not yet supported. I'll stay with python for now. Thanks!